# invalid model identifier: 'sites.site'

Tags: python, json, django

When I try to run `manage.py syncdb`, I get this error:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/cbplusd/repos/wibo1/fixtures/initial_data.json': Invalid model identifier: 'sites.site'
```

My installed_apps in my `settings.py` no longer contains `django.contrib.sites`, and my .json file looks like this:

```
[    
    {

       "pk": 1, 
        "model": "sites.site", 
        "fields": {
            "domain": "localhost:8000", 
            "name": "wibo"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 2, 
        "model": "sites.site", 
        "fields": {
            "domain": "example.com", 
            "name": "wibo"
        }
    }
]
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `"model": "sites.site"` tells Django to look for an app directory named `sites`, containing a `models.py` file that defines a `Site` model.

Comment: It's so clear for me. If you've decided you don't need the django.contrib.sites app then you only need to delete the fixture file. By doing that, django won't try to load it.

Comment: ^^^ you were right, all I needed to do was delete this whole thing. Thank you so much!